# iTerm colors for Prompt, Command, and Output

Tags: bash, iterm

Right now my iTerm2 looks like this...

[image]

Everything is the same color and is hard to read. Can I make any of the Prompt, Command, and Output different colors like this?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[There's a pretty exhaustive description of editing the bash prompt here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt) there might be some linux specific stuff, but most of it is generic bash stuff.

But just for getting started, I recommend [this bash profile generator](http://xta.github.io/HalloweenBash/)

It is pretty simple, so I've since learned more and my prompt looks like:
[image: dwightk's bash prompt]

using:

```
[[ -s "/Users/dwightk/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/dwightk/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

function parse_git_branch {
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="  \[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h:\[\033[01;34m\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[01;32m\]\w \[\033[01;34m\]\n>\[\e[0m\]"
```

which is pretty useful when dealing with git. Everything before the `export PS1=` is what enables the git branch to appear.

The  is from my first foray into bash prompt editing [after I read this blog post.](http://notes.torrez.org/2013/04/put-a-burger-in-your-shell.html)

Comment: Hopefully someone with a better grasp of the actual editing of the prompt can post a more cogent answer.

Comment:  <- Is that char intented?

Comment: yeah, it's a leftover from my first expedition into bash prompt editing after reading: http://notes.torrez.org/2013/04/put-a-burger-in-your-shell.html I liked it so it stayed around.

Comment: That git function is really nice. Will save be some git branch -a cmd's.

Comment: colored git output is nice too. https://thomashunter.name/blog/git-colored-output-shortcut-commands-autocompletion-and-bash-prompt/

Comment: While this is a nice answer, especially the funny  part, it is not a correct one as it doesn't really tell how to set a different color for command and output - only for the prompt. Anyone knows the right answer?

Comment: I think I got it right in my answer, @jeremyjjbrown . It would be cool if you could change the accepted answer to mine. :)

Answer (score 14):

AFAIK there is no any UNIXy way to color **anything else** than the prompt.

But as you asked for an iTerm2 solution you are in luck! Use the [Triggers feature](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html) to color text matching regexp.

For example if your prompts looks like this:

[image]

..then add in iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Triggers , [Edit] a Trigger like this:

[image]

..that will match the **command** part of each line, which will start to look like this:

[image]

Voilà - you have different colors for prompt, command and output! :)

Comment: This is simpler for most folks I bet so upvoted. But since the other one will work in any term, even remotely and it colors the git prompt as well, I'm going to keep it as the accepted answer.

Comment: What font do you use?

Comment: @towry : Consolas

Comment: You could very easily put something like `\e[95m` at the end of your PS1 var and that would do it

Comment: Thanks @SamyBencherif, but this will also color the output with the same color as command, which was not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The iTerm solution works but there seems to be a slight delay in the coloring. If one stops typing for a second, the whole line is colored as expected.

Comment: That's true. I haven't found a better solution though. PS This should rather be a comment, not an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Try it and let me know.

http://dobsondev.com/2014/02/21/customizing-your-terminal/

The approach involves adding some instructions to your bash profile.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh you could do like this:

Add this code into your ~/.zshrc file

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }
precmd_functions+=( precmd_ves_info)
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats ':%b'
PROMPT=' %F{040}%n%f at %F{166}%m%f in %F{031}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%f%F{magenta}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%f %# '
```

Then reload your profile

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

It should look like this:
[image]

I like this example because it shows a bit of how you can use colour codes or colour names