# bash prompt acting weird when I click UP key and then down KEY

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, bash

So my bash prompt looks like this `[parth:~]$` and if I go `cd` to Desktop, it looks like this `[parth:Desktop]$`. I only want to see the current directory, next to my username so if I go to a folder, in Desktop, it would replace Desktop with the current directory name.

This is what I have in my `~/.bash_profile` to make it look like this: `export PS1='[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]]\$ '`

This PS1 also follows the color highlighting of my terminal theme.

The problem is that when I click the up arrow key a few times (for the previous commands) and then click the down arrow key, the prompt gets messed up. It appends a part of the previous command to my prompt and I have to enter `CTRL + C` to reset it. Also when my command reaches the end of the line, instead of going to the new line, it wraps around the same line.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple of begin indicators for the non-printing escape sequences.

You should use this:

```
PS1='[\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]]\$ '
```

And don't export PS1, it is not an environment variable.

Some discussion about that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247585/to-export-or-not-to-export-bash-ps1-variable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to tell, this is caused by a bug in iTerm2, where actions such as ctrl+a make it act as though the colour-specifying characters in PS1 are treated as though they have a length.

The best solution I have found is to not specify colours in your .bashrc, and instead use [triggers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252001) to generate the colours.

Comment: iTerm2 would not know or care about the color sequences.  It is the shell not knowing that some of the characters in the prompt are non-printing.  The OP missed a couiple of sequence starting escapes.